Does Updating An OS Mess Up Dual Booting
I bought a new laptop. It has a 1 TB SSD. I am considering making a 200 to 300 gig partition to install and try Linux. I am worried that updating one of the operating systems could delete or corrupt the other os. Is this a serious risk and should I use a VM to avoid this issue?

This question is similar to: Risks of dual booting Ubuntu and Kali vs Ubuntu and Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Even if not dual booting, you must have good backups. Windows manages to break on its own. With good backup, reinstall & restore of your data then is relatively easy. Another alternative is to use an external drive. I used full install on flash drives but they were very slow writing. Have full installs on external SSD and they almost are as fast as internal SSD. External SSD has same data & configuration as main working desktop system, so, in effect, another backup.

@oldfred's advice is excellent. Heed it! Good preparation reduces a crisis to a mild annoyance.

You still have the boot problem, windows appears to reset it at times. I'd rather recommend to use a virtual machine for trying out Linux, then swap to have Linux as host system if liking Linux and swapping to it.

This system has been dual boot (3 installed OSes on this box) since I purchased it very early last year... and I've experienced no issues... HOWEVER the OSes involved do matter & you provided no clues.. I have >6 boxes here that all dual boot with multiple OSes & have no issues on them either... but experience will vary depending on what you actually have installed.  I do have minor issue with a non-Ubuntu that somewhat regularly offers dual boot, but a single command fixes that anyway (messages on screen warn me when it happens)
